# Restriction of hypersurfaces to canonically embedded curve is surjective?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let C be a canonically embedded curve (irreducible, projective, smooth, over an algebraically closed field) of genus g at least 3, in particular not hyperelliptic. Is the restriction map of degree d hypesurfaces to the global sections of the d-th power of the canonical line bundle of C surjective? (i.e. is the map $H^0(\mathbb{P}^{g-1},\mathcal{O}(d))\to H^0(C,\omega_C^{\otimes d})$ surjective?)

I am most interested in the cases g=4, d=3 and g=5, d=2, where I know this needs to be true for dimensional reasons (using that dim M_g = 3g-3), but of course I want to go in the other direction.

Comment: Please look up Noether's theorem, for example in the book on curves by Arbarello et. al.